Nuxt3: emitting an input value from a sign up form
In my Nuxt3 application, I'm trying to emit the value entered in an email input field from a child component (SignForm.vue) to the parent component (signup.vue) so I can use it to register a new user
signup.vue
<script setup>
    const props = {
        fields: [
            "email",
            "password",
            "confirm",
        ],
        header: "Register a new account",
        button: [
            {
                text: "Sign Up",
                color: "green-500",
            }
        ]
    };

    const email = ref('');
    const password = ref('');
    const confirm = ref('');

    function signUp(email) {
        console.log(email)
    
    }
</script>

<template>
    <SignForm :props="props" @method="signUp"/>
</template>

SignForm.vue
<script setup>
    const email = ref('');
    const password = ref('');
    const { props } = defineProps(['props']);
</script>

<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="flex flex-col items-center gap-2">
            <p class="text-2xl pb-2">{{ props.header }}</p>
            <input v-for="(pf, index) in props.fields" :key="index"
            :type="[`${pf}` === 'confirm' ? 'password' : `${pf}`]"
            :placeholder="`${pf}`"
            :v-model="`${pf}`"
            class="bg-gray-300 rounded p-2 w-2/5"
            >
            <button type="submit" v-for="(btn, index) in props.button" :key="index"
                class="p-2 text-white rounded w-2/5 text-sm opacity-85 hover:font-bold hover:opacity-100"
                :class="`bg-${ btn.color }`"
                @click.prevent="$emit('method', email)"
                >
                <span>{{ btn.text }}</span>
            </button>
        </form>    
    </div>
</template>

The email value still isn't being emitted as expected - it's either empty or undefined
UPDATED:
https://play.vuejs.org/

Problem with the above code is that you are trying to bind string value, instead of reactive value because of this there is no change shown in the email from the SignForm.vue.
Easy solution of this would be to create a reactive object with stores the key: field name and value: input value. It can done using both ref or reactive functions
Vue Playground
SOLUTION
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const form = ref({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  const { props } = defineProps(['props']);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <p>{{ props.header }}</p>
      <input v-for="pf in props.fields" 
      :type="`${pf}`"
      :placeholder="`${pf}`"
      v-model="form[pf]"
      >
      <button type="submit" v-for="btn in props.button" 
        @click.prevent="$emit('method', form.email)"
        >
        {{ btn.text }}
      </button>
    </form>    
  </div>
</template>


This is not dynamic but definitely works yes.

form reference can still function properly even with an empty object like this const form= ref<Record<string, string>>({});

Here is a quick reproduction example of how it is supposed to work.
You can use the Vue devtools to inspect further and try to find out what is emitted from the child component. Also, I think that removing some v-for might help debug the thing more easily.
PS: do not use index as a :key.

I actually think that your issue is the fact that you expect to have the email from the child, but you have a local email from the parent. So, you're probably receiving the $event up as expected but you're console.logging the local one which is empty.
Please try
<SignForm :props="props" @method="console.log($event)" />

In that case, $event should be the email ref emitted from the child.
PS2: maybe consider not having two identically named email refs with 1 depth level difference for your own debugging and ease of use purposes.

More info regarding $event in the docs.

Thanks @kissu!
I think the problem is v-model directive inside the first v-for loop, it binds the correct value (email in this case) but it's not picked up by the @click event somehow. When I change it to a not dynamic value like v-model="email" it works as expected

I've attached a link to my https://play.vuejs.org/ in my original question
